# IThumbnailProvider equivalent for Windows 8

Tags: c++, shell, com, thumbnails, windows-8

I have a shell extension that uses `IThumbnailProvider` and `IInitializeWithStream` interfaces to generate thumbnail previews for the registered file types. It's working great on Windows 7 but it doesn't work on Windows 8.

I've found out that Windows 8 has 2 new related interfaces: `IThumbnailCachePrimer` and `IThumbnailSettings`. But the preliminary documentation of Microsoft doesn't explain anything...

Does anybody have some info about how the preview control system has changed in Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, actually, the thumbnail processing in Windows 8 Consumer Preview still works with the WinVista/7 API.
It's just that by default Win8 doesn't come with the vc++ runtimes, but only the .net versions of those runtimes...silly error :/

Well, at least now it works in Desktop mode although quite slowly. The poor performance is maybe due to the fact　ｍｙ Win8 is still a beta ｒｕｎｎｉｎｇ　ｗｉｔｈｉｎ　ａ　ｖｉｒｔｕａｌ　ｍａｃｈｉｎｅ．